# ** Anyone else having trouble logging in to SSD? **

Tags: untagged

I know I know, if someone is having problems logging in then they won't be able to post a reply... But I had to phrase it as a question right?

But on a serious note I've been encountering problems trying to log in to the site. It just happens that luckily on one of my computers I was still logged in...

I've emailed Andrew to let him know, if he wasn't already. I know this isn't a Sound Design question but I thought I'd 'flag' it on here so that others having the same problem know it's been reported etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks so much for pointing that out! I'll now send an urgent email to the people that can help on that front. Hopefully there's a quick solution! In the meantime, everyone, please don't log out...

Comment: No, but my most recent question from a couple of days ago has completely disappeared ever since the site underwent maintenance...

Comment: Oh no, @Alex! I'm so sorry about that! Will try figure that one out too. What was the title of your question? Or even better, the link? 

Comment: No worries, @Andrew. Unfortunately I can't remember the exact title. The keywords were "long tones" and it was something along the lines of "Creating long evocative tones" or something similar.

Comment: Yay, all working again =P

Comment: I lost points from a 'up' answer on @Alex's question. This makes sense now.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it was a specific misconfiguration - since fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Hi guys,

The issue has been fixed. I'm so sorry about this! When the migration happened there was an error in an SSL proxy in the configuration, but it was found and resolved.

So now we can all login and out with no worries :-)

Answer (score 0):

Been locked out of the site for a few days, but looks like it works now.